# Would it be feasible to have Camera on the bat and ball?

Tags: cricket

In current days, a camera is present everywhere - the stumps, boundary, umpire's hat etc. Would it be possible to have a camera on bat and ball as well? How would it disturb the aerodynamics of bat and ball?

Comment: Can I ask why you want cameras on the bat and ball? Is it just for an interesting perspective or are you trying to collect data about the game? In Major League Baseball, every pitch is tracked, enabling research about the skills of pitchers, batters, catchers, and umpires. I'm sure an equivalent system could be set up in cricket.

Comment: It is just for interesting perspective..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically possible, you could mount a small wireless camera in the ball but and something similar in the bat.

However in the ball it would only be able to face in one direction and there would be no gaurentee that would be of any interest.  The repeated impact forces would probably destroy it fairly quickly, and it would also alter the weight of the ball and probably change the way the ball is made to be able to fit the camera in so I doubt it will ever be attempted.

For the bat it would be easier to ensure it looked in the right direction but motion bluring would be an issue and then you would have the impact issues around the lifespan of the camera.  It would also introduce a structual weakness in to the bat.  Or if surface mounted would effect the pick up and stroke of the bat.

So its extremely unlikely to happen.